# Linking a Package as a Lerna Package Dependency for Development

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, monorepo, lerna

The structure of my project is as follows:

```
packages/
    client/
        package.json
    server/
        package.json
    shared/
        package.json
lerna.json
package.json
```

The package.json file of `client` contains the following dependencies:

```
{
    "name": "@my-project/client",
    "dependencies": {
        // ...
        "@my-project/shared": "*",
        "cool-components": "^1.0.0',
        // ...
    }
}
```

`@my-project/shared` is the package name of the `packages/shared` directory.

I am willing to use `npm link` to develop the `cool-components` library, and to use `npm link` to use its code within `@my-project/client`.

Currently, I tried to run:

```
cd packages/client
npm link cool-components
```

And for unlinking:

```
npm unlink cool-components
```

But, I get an error claiming that `@my-project/shared` is not in the NPM registry.

This is absolutely understandable; When I run NPM commands in the scope of `@my-project/client`, it is not familiar with its sibling packages, and it tries to look for this package in the registry. This is the reason we should use `lerna add` in the root instead of `npm install` within each package.

Even though I understand the cause, I couldn't find a proper way to use `npm link` to develop another package while using it within my Lerna monorepo.

Answer (score 4):

You add `@my-project/shared` dependency to `@my-project/client` with:

```
 // this creates link between packages
 lerna add @my-project/shared --scope=@my-project/client
```

Now if you check node modules inside `@my-project/client` you should see
`@my-project/shared`.

If you want to access a dependency in your node package, you use

`require.resolve`:
// require.resolve will get you the absolute path

```
const packagePath = require.resolve("@my-project/build/index.js");

// to use the this package, for exampe in express.static
// path.dirname will give you path until build directory
// so you are going to serve up that folder
app.use(express.static(path.dirname(packagePath)));
```

in client side, importing module from node modules path should work without any configuration. If it does not, try to resolve the node modules path to absolute path.